# Cut polygon layer into a new subset by the boundaries of another polygon layer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, spatial-analysis

ArcGIS 10.2.1

I have a feature class of wetland mapping. It is a series of various polygons, all irregular shapes and sizes.

I also have a parcel boundary feature class that is basically even sized rectangular polygons.

I am trying to divide the wetland polygons into a "subset", where the polygons are "cut" by the boundaries of the parcels, that way I can get area estimates per parcel of how much wetlands each parcel has.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [identity tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/identity.htm). Wetland polygons as input layers and parcel boundaries  as identity features. The tool requires an advanced license. The output feature class has the attributes of both inputs.